# .NET AutoResetEvent: How to know if the process is waiting for (method WaitOne)?

Tags: .net, process, autoresetevent

I call in my process method "WaitOne", I need to know another method if the process is waiting.

¿I can I know this about my WaitHandle?

Declaration:

```
private static EventWaitHandle WaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Call:

```
WaitHandle.WaitOne()
```

**Edit**

The process, by an event, a data request, and wait until it is sent, when it receives the data proceed to execute the method "`WaitHandle.set()`".

But the user can also request the cancellation of the process, in that request I need to know if the process is waiting.

Comment: If you need to know, you're probably doing something wrong. Why do you need to know?

Comment: This is not possible, it is a fundamental threading race.  Not clear what you want to do, but it sure sounds that you need *two* events.  One that signals the normal operation, another that signals the cancellation.  Use WaitAny() to test, the canceling one first.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why you need to know if something is waiting on an event. You should redesign your logic to not require this. Normally this can be done by using a ManualResetEvent instead. Otherwise, you'll probably have to use a lock and a flag that indicates if a listener is listening.